# SpriteKit: SKSpriteNode containing another SKSpriteNodes but only one SKPhysicsBody

Tags: ios, physics, sprite-kit

I have a character in my game, it's an SKSpriteNode with few child SKSpriteNodes so I can animate various parts of my character (hands, feet etc.), it also has 1 SKSpriteNode (tried replacing with SKNode, but it was the same) with SKPhysicsBody for a body.

When I add the character to my layer in a scene it just hang in the position and the sprite with the body falls down.

My question and problem is: How can I keep all the child sprites in my main character sprite -  how can I keep my character together?

Thanks for any ideas!

EDIT: How can I keep the child sprite with the body attached to my container sprite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Re EDIT:

Use an SKNode to control all of your character's body parts, including the main body:

```
SKNode (controller)
  SKSpriteNode (head)
  SKSpriteNode (body)
  SKSpriteNode (leg1)
  SKSpriteNode (leg2)
```

That gives you more flexibility.

To make the head the "master" position, this should do the trick:

```
-(void) didSimulatePhysics
{
    self.parent.position = [self convertPoint:self.position toNode:self.parent.parent];
    self.position = CGPointZero;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing exacly that but let's say I need to attach physics body only to the "head" SKSpriteNode and that the "head" moves the entire "controller". Not that the "head" just leaves the container responsing to gravity, but I need it to "take" the "controller" with it. Hope you know what I mean :)

Comment: Oh my, didSimulatePhysics... I totally forgot that. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

The body is falling because its responding to gravity, as expected. The Other body part, if they do not have physics bodies will stay where you place them.

Some options :

1.

If you want all body parts to be physics body then I suggest looking at a joints, ie a pin joint - which will work like a shoulder joint for example.

Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342417/sprite-kit-pin-joints-appear-to-have-an-incorrect-anchor/19343909#19343909) of pin joints for making a car with wheels.

2.

If you just want it not move, for whatever reason. On your physics body, just set this.

```
bodyNode.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Smick. Yes, I understand that, but I didn't explained what I want as precisly as I wanted. I want the character (containing all the child sprites) to follow the child sprite with the body. Sry for my english, hope you got my point now :)

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you right, you can start off by saying the gravity on the SKScene is 0, by doing

```
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0,0);
```

This will ensure that nothing causes the character of your screen to fall down into the bottom from the gravity enforced on the screen.

Answer (score -1):

Possible solution: remove SKPhysicBody from child node and add it to parent node.

Comment: But I need the SKPhysicsBody to be in a child node not in the root node of my character